# I am wondering: what is the purpose of SQL server (2019 or all server editions) not having a User Interface?

Tags: sql-server

I have started learning about SQL in my university course and finding SQL as a new developer was confusing. A because there was no user interface and B because so many other tools were installed as well. What is the reason behind having no user interface for SQL but the set of tools? Is it not easier to combine them together (tell me if I have missed any details).

Comment: What do you mean by user interface?

Comment: Relational databases like SQL Server are part of a [client-server model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model) where database services are separate from client applications and tools that use them. This architecture provides benefits like workload distribution and scalability. Products like Microsoft Access combine a RDBMS with an application/tools UI, facilitating development of single-user or small workgroup apps but will not scale beyond a limited number of users.

Answer (score 1):

As a developer you can use SQL Server Management Studio(SSMS) as a user interface
or SQL Server data Tools (SSDT)
It is true you need to download them and install separately

Comment: Thank you for your help